# await.Messages doesn't work. It skip all comands in it

Tags: async-await, discord.js

```
if(!db['mention'].length)
            {
              message.channel.send("Komenda wymaga wzmianki gracza");
            }
          else if(db['mention'].includes("@"))
            {
              
              db['v1'] = message.mentions.members.first().voice.channelId;
              if(db[`value`]<=10 && db[`value`]>=1)
                {
                  ping()
                }
              else
              {
                  message.channel.send(`Wpisz ilość od 1 do 10`).then(() => {
                  message.channel.awaitMessages({
                  filter: (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id,
                  max: 1,
                  time: 6000,
                  errors: ['time'],
                }).then(message => { 
                  db['value'] = message.first();
                  if (db['value']<=10 && db['value']>=1) 
                  { 
                    ping() 
                  } 
                  else 
                  {
                    message.channel.send(`Błędna wartość`)
                  }
                  
                })
                .catch(collected => {
                  message.channel.send('Timeout')
                })
                })
            }
          }
```

this part in code is skipped

```
.then(message => { 
                  db['value'] = message.first();
                  if (db['value']<=10 && db['value']>=1) 
                  { 
                    ping() 
                  }
```

and bot only send Timeout. I remember that this was working one month ago. I was looking for solution in internet but i founded nothing.

Did somebody know what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how it will interact with code not showing (ping() function and any db code) but the rest should work

```js
const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id
message.channel.send(`Wpisz ilość od 1 do 10`).then(() => {
    message.channel.awaitMessages({
        filter,
        max: 1,
        time: 6000,
        errors: ['time'],
    }).catch(() => {
       throw new Error('Timed Out')
    }).then(message => { 
        db['value'] = message.first();
        setTimeout(() => {
            message.delete()
        }, 10000)
        if (db['value'] <= 10 && db['value'] >= 1) {
            ping()
        } else {
            message.channel.send(`Błędna wartość`)
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        switch (error.message) {
            case 'Timed Out':
                message.channel.send('Timeout');
            break
    })
})
```

Comment: I added line after message.first() - message.first().delete(10000); Do u know why it delete immediately? It should delete after 10 sec

Comment: As of v13 message.delete() doesn’t accept any options aside from the message id I updated my answer to include the message delete option the way you will need to make it